# Subclassing UILocalNotification for property addition

Tags: properties, uilocalnotification

I tried to cancel localNotifications with specific tag number. It's my favorite manner to use tag number for compare logic.

So, I subclassed UILocalNotification and add property NSInteger tag. Then use the subclass instance for scheduling localNotification.

> CustomNotification *customNoti = [[CustomNotification alloc] init];
>   customNoti.fireDate = myDate;
>     customNoti.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
>     customNoti.tag = self.tag;      // crash
>    // error : -[UIConcreteLocalNotification setTag:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75a3630

Here is CustomNotification.h file

> `#import   <UIKit/UIKit.h>`
>
> @interface CustomNotification : UILocalNotification
>
> @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger tag;
>   @end

Why is it crash and 'unrecognized selector' message shown? Is UILocalNotification class special? I can't find any missed code.